# Unable to build Uno Platform UWP template project

Tags: c#, uwp, uno-platform

Decided to experiment with the Uno Platform, so I followed the instructions here: https://platform.uno/docs/articles/get-started.html

Set up a new solution in VS2019 16.6.4 using the *Cross-Platform App (Uno Platform)* template, then updated all the NuGet packages.

Without changing a line of code, I'm unable to build the solution (or just the UWP project). With UWP/x86 selected, I get these two build errors:

> Error CS1929  'ILoggerFactory' does not contain a definition for
> 'AddConsole' and the best extension method overload
> 'ConsoleLoggerExtensions.AddConsole(ILoggingBuilder,
> Action)' requires a receiver of type
> 'ILoggingBuilder' [PROJECT].Droid, [PROJECT].UWP, [PROJECT].Wasm,
> [PROJECT].iOS,
> [PROJECT].macOS   [PATH] \ [PROJECT].Shared\App.xaml.cs   116 Active

> Error CS1061  'App' does not contain a definition for
> 'InitializeComponent' and no accessible extension method
> 'InitializeComponent' accepting a first argument of type 'App' could
> be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)   [PROJECT].Droid, [PROJECT].UWP, [PROJECT].Wasm,
> [PROJECT].iOS,
> [PROJECT].macOS   [PATH] \ [PROJECT].Shared\App.xaml.cs   116 Active

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade your Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter nuget packages to version 1.1.1